# how to get my base class through my virtual class

Tags: c#, interface

I'm studding up on C# class interfaces and I'm stuck.

This is my interface currently.

```
public abstract class AgnosticDevice
{
    public abstract void SomeDeviceOperation();
}

public class vJoystick : AgnosticDevice, Joystick
{
    public vJoystick( DirectInput di, Guid g){}
    public override void SomeDeviceOperation()
    {
        /* Joystick operation */
    }
}

public class vMouse : AgnosticDevice, Mouse
{
    public vMouse( DirectInput di ){}
    public override void SomeDeviceOperation()
    {
        /* Mouse operation */
    }
}

public class vKeyboard : AgnosticDevice, Keyboard
{
    public vKeyboard( DirectInput di , Guid g){}
    public override void SomeDeviceOperation()
    {
        /* Keyboard operation */
    }
}

public class DeviceFactory
{
    public static AgnosticDevice Create( string type, DirectInput di, Guid g )
    {
        if ( type == "Mouse" )
        {
            return new vMouse( di);
        }
        if ( type == "Joystick" )
        {
            return new vJoystick( di, g);
        }
        if ( type == "Keyboard" )
        {
            return new vKeyboard( di, g);
        }
        return new vJoystick( di, g ); //default
    }
}
```

Please understand I'm still learning here but I think this is close to what I want. Now the Joystick, Mouse, and Keyboard are Dirrect X classes. I want to make it so that I can have a device called "device" in my code agnostic to what type it is. Each one of those classed have similar members. So instead of making 3 classes I really want one class and have 3 interfaces for each type.

Now my current problem is how to construct it. Normally with any of those classes you do a simple new like
Joystick device = new Joystick ( directInput, deviceGuid );
but in my case I need to do a 
device = (vJoystick)DeviceFactory.Create( type, directInput, deviceGuid );
but as you can clearly see device is never really made. vJoystick never returns a new Joystick. This is were I'm lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not support multiple inheritance, so you can't derive from more than a single class.

In your case, you'd need to have your classes encapsulate the Joystick and Mouse classes, which would allow you to use the normal factory methods.  You could then create and implement an `IJoystick` or `IMouse` interface along with your `AgnosticDevice` class, if that would make your life simpler.

Comment: C# does support multiple interfaces though, which in many cases is good enough.

Comment: @Nate Yes - I edited to include that, but in this case, the OP is trying to subclass a third party (DirectX) class along with their own.

Comment: I followed your advice but can not quite get the syntax right. Did my research but finding an example using a 3rd party class is not easy to find. Can any one give a code example to help me with the syntax?

Comment: @SeanGreen For many examples of encapsulation in C#, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7445676/65358